# Formulario no guarda los datos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

No sé por qué no guarda los datos mi formulario, cuando ya he hecho todo la conexión, la creación de la tabla, insertar los valores respectivos y hice todo el código como creo que debería de funcionar, sí me crea la tabla, pero los datos del formulario no se añaden a la base de datos, no sé en qué me equivoqué, agradecería su ayuda!

Aquí adjunto los datos que he utilizado en cada archivo de mi proyecto.

Datos.php

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    $nombre_completo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['nombre_completo']);
    $correo_electronico = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['correo_electronico']);
    $telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['telefono']);
    $curso = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['curso']);
    $mensaje = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['mensaje']);

    $envio="INSERT INTO registro (id_registro,nombre_completo,correo_electronico,telefono,curso,mensaje) VALUES (NULL,'$nombre_completo','$correo_electronico','$telefono','$curso','$mensaje')";

    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$envio);
?>
```

Conexion.php

```
<?php
    $host= "localhost";
    $user= "root";
    $pass= "";
    $db= "proyecto_final_pa";

    $conexion=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
?>
```

Index.php

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");

    $envio="CREATE TABLE registro (id_registro INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, nombre_completo VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
                        correo_electronico VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, telefono CHAR(9) NOT NULL, curso VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
                        mensaje VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id_registro))";

    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$envio);
    header("location:registro.php");
?>
```

Registro.php

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="datos.php" data-sb-form-api-token="API_TOKEN">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="nombre_completo" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre..." data-sb-validations="required" />
                            <label for="name">Nombre completo</label>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="name:required">El nombre completo es obligatorio.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="correo_electronico" type="email" placeholder="ejemplo@dominio.com" data-sb-validations="required,email" />
                            <label for="email">Correo electronico</label>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="email:required">El correo es obligatorio.</div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="email:email">El correo NO es válido.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="telefono" type="tel" placeholder="(+51) 968154089" data-sb-validations="required" />
                            <label for="phone">Teléfono</label>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="phone:required">El teléfono es obligatorio.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <select class="form-select" id="curso" name="curso" required data-sb-validations="required">
                                <option selected disabled value="">Escoja un curso...</option>
                                <option>WORDPRESS</option>
                                <option>JOOMLA</option>
                                <option value="cchar">C#</option>
                                <option value="java">JAVA</option>
                                <option value="photoshop">PHOTOSHOP</option>
                                <option value="coreldraw">CORELDRAW</option>
                              </select>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="curso:required">La seleccion del curso es obligatorio.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="mensaje" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu mensaje..." style="height: 10rem" data-sb-validations="required"></textarea>
                            <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
                            <div>El mensaje es obligatorio.</div>
                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>Envío de formulario exitoso!</div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="d-none" id="submitErrorMessage"><div class="text-center text-danger mb-3">¡Error al enviar el mensaje!</div></div>
                        <button name="ENVIAR" type="submit" value="ENVIAR">ENVIAR</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: consulta ¿al momento de intentar insertar la información de la base de datos, te aparece algún error de php en pantalla?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Me lo parece a mi o se esta creando la tabla en cada petición? Ese comando seguramente de error una vez este la tabla creada

Answer (score 1):

Buenass, No tengo mucha cancha en esto pero agrégale

```
    if (isset($_POST['ENVIAR'])) { 
        $nombre_completo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['nombre_completo']);
        $correo_electronico = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['correo_electronico']);
        $telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['telefono']);
        $curso = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['curso']);
        $mensaje = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['mensaje']);
    
        $envio="INSERT INTO registro (id_registro,nombre_completo,correo_electronico,telefono,curso,mensaje) VALUES (NULL,'$nombre_completo','$correo_electronico','$telefono','$curso','$mensaje')";
    
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$envio);}
```

otra cosa, es que te fijes pagina por pagina, (localhost/carpeta/Registro.php) o con la de datos.php y ver si te salta algo

y un echo a $envio a ver que te devuelve